# How to remove Ubuntu and Install Windows

Tags: 14.04, live-cd, windows-10

I have Ubuntu 14.04. I installed it on my computer but now would like to remove it to install Windows. I cannot  get the computer to boot from DVD so the windows install will not load. what can I do?

Comment: You could try using Unetbootin to burn the Windows ISO to a flash drive.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the steps by step described. Hope this is useful for you. 
        Ref.
[How To Remove Ubuntu 13.04 Installed Alongside Windows 8](http://www.scrollstory.com/linux/remove-ubuntu-13-easily/32/)

Steps To Remove Ubuntu Easily:

NOTE:This method is applicable for most of the Linux Operating system’s.

1. Use a Live USB/DVD with Ubuntu and boot using it.
2. Choose “Try Ubuntu”, go to edit network connections connect with internet (set up your internet connection and remain connected with internet)
3. Open Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) on Ubuntu and use these lines of code :
       ---> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
       ---> sudo apt-get update
       ---> sudo apt-get install -y os-uninstaller && os-uninstaller
   Press Enter after entering each line of code and wait for the process to be completed.

   Basically we’ll be using an app called os-uninstaller found in Ubuntu repository.OS-uninstaller will automatically be launched if not then find it here:System->Administration->OS-Uninstaller menu if you use Gnome, or via the dash if you use UnityChoose the OS you want to uninstall/remove.A confirmation will appear, Click Apply to start the removal.

AlSO SEE:[Official website of OS-Uninstaller](http://technikaly.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/os-uninstaller)

Note: There may be numerous other methods but this one is pretty simple and less prone to errors (best for newbies).

```
 Now Restart Your PC and it’ll boot into your windows.

 Follow these steps to regain your lost space (The space Ubuntu has been using)

1. Right-click on computer and select Manage.
2. Go to Disk Management.
3. The windows partitions will usually be wrapped in green, look to right of this green box. the partitions to right of it are usually created by Ubuntu.
4. Delete Those Volume’s and they’ll go into that green box and will form a single volume.
5. Now Format the volume.
6. Right-click on the last NTFS volume and select Extend volume and then Next to complete the process.
Now you’ll regain your drive space you’ve lost to Ubuntu.
```

And yes, you can change the drive letter’s if they are not displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get to the boot screen on your system.  During boot up when you see the computer manufacturer's screen that is where it tells you what key to tap for getting to the boot screen.  On mine it is F12 (Dell) and there I can choose which boot device I wish to use just for the one time.  So if it were me I would have the windows disk in the drive and reboot.  When I see the Dell screen tap F12 and then choose CD/DVD to boot and it would then boot the bootable media.  Good Luck!

Comment: Check also this post if you have problems entering BIOS setup: http://www.pcworld.com/article/241032/how_to_enter_your_pcs_bios.html